# believe him in OR believe him

Tags: prepositions

> He thanked the manager for believing **him** to accomplish this task with efficiency.
>
> He thanked the manager for believing **in him** to accomplish this task with efficiency.

Is is necessary that the preposition **in** has to be placed between **believing** and **him**?

I thought **believe** can take a object, so the preposition here doesn't seem necessasry,
but it was marked wrong and **in** was added to it.

By the way, with the preposition **in**,
the implied subject of the infinitive **to accomplish this task with efficienct** is still **him**, am i right?

Answer (score 1):

**believe in somebody** is a phrasal verb meaning **to feel that you can trust somebody and or they will be successful**

> We need a leader we can believe in.